# Set current location in a route based on a arbitrary distance

Tags: here-api

I'm just playing around with Here and this is my escenario for an idea.

- Get a routing between 2 points, [I know this is doable](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/routing.html)
- Set the start and finish marker, [I know this is doable](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/routing.html)
- Get the distance between the 2 points, [I know this is doable](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/routing.html)

Now, if the distance from point 1 and 2 is 3000 meters I want to set a marker ( You are here ) based on a arbitrary distance value, let say I want to add a marker at the 1750 meters point, the market should appears in the half route way.

Is this posible with the actual API?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do with HERE javascript API.

Once you get routing response and create `H.geo.LineString` out of it, you can calculate distance between each two geo points from that line string using [H.geo.Point#distance](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.geo.Point.html#distance) method. This will help to determine between which two points (lat, lng) is your desired arbitrary distance.

After that you need to [calculate angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809179/angle-between-2-gps-coordinates) between these two geo points and use it in method [H.geo.Point#walk](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.geo.Point.html#walk) in order to get exact position of the geo point you need.

Here you can find [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/1vwqn7hz/) which places marker on the simple LineString based on desired arbitrary distance.